# jBPM6 - embed web designer in existing application

Tags: embed, designer, jbpm

Are you aware of any guide / tutorial / example project that might help me embed the jBPM web designer in an existing web application? 
Namely:

- Which are the maven libraries I need to include?
- Is it possible to deploy the designer specific components in the main application WAR (this is after all what embedded means)?
- How can I access the designer? Is there a specific URL for it?

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: I am more or less trying to find out the same thing. What I found out so far: https://developer.jboss.org/message/911590 . If you found out something, please let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately we were forced to develop a custom editor for this as we were unable to integrate the provided one. I will, although try your solution for which I thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found out how to do it.

What you need is a running instance of the KIE workbench (seems this was once formerly called Drools Guvnor). You can get a demo system up and running very fast using the jBPM installer. A written guide on how to do it can be found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/jBPMInstaller.html). In my case I downloaded the `jbpm-6.1.0.Final-installer-full.zip` from [here](http://jbpm.org/download/download.html).

As soon as you have the JBoss AS/WildFly with the KIE workbench running you can access it through `http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console/`.

Now each BPMN process saved in the KIE workshop seems to have a unique path which is also a Git repository URL. When you open a diagram and go to the metadata tab this path is listed as URI.

To display this BPMN process inside a custom-built web application with the jBPM Designer BPMN 2 editor, just create an `iframe` HTML element with that URL in it like the following example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p>Editor frame below:</p>
    <iframe height='800' src='http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console?standalone=&path=git://master@jbpm-playground/HR/src/main/resources/hiring.bpmn2' width='1000'></iframe>

  </body>
</html>
```

As soon as you load that page, the editor will be embedded into the page via that `iframe`. This works even with a static HTML page without a web server, so it should be quite versatile and your web application surely doesn't need to run inside the same JBoss AS/WildFly instance and doesn't even need to be written in Java.

What I did not figure out so far is how to create new BPMN processes via some kind of API, which could then be edited within the standalone web application. Also I don't know how access control is supposed to work yet.