# Embed JBPM Web Designer inside an app and/or use an API to generate BPMN?

Tags: jboss, jbpm, bpmn

I am looking to embed JBPM Web Designer inside an application.

While I found another [thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565878/jbpm6-embed-web-designer-in-existing-application) on a similar topic, there were still questions about being able to use an API to generate BPMN.

Does anyone know of a solution for this?

Comment: What thread exactly? Edit your question to include a link to that thread.

Comment: (updated the question with thread in reference)